# Append to tuples in list using another list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

For eg:

```
a = [('x',4),('y',1),('z',5)]
b = [6,2,3]
c = []
```

output will be

```
c = [('x',4,6),('y',1,2),('z',5,3)]
```

I tried this:

```
for i in b:
    for data in a: 
        x,y = data
        c.append((x,y,i))
```

But I'm not getting the correct result. I get this instead:

```
[('x', 4, 6), ('y', 1, 6), ('z', 5, 6), ('x', 4, 2), ('y', 1, 2), ('z', 5, 2), ('x', 4, 3), ('y', 1, 3), ('z', 5, 3)]
```

Comment: You should really [edit] things like that into your question. I did so for you now.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip `a` and `b` together using the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to produce new tuples:

```
c = [a + (b,) for a, b in zip(a, b)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [('x',4),('y',1),('z',5)]
>>> b = [6,2,3]
>>> [a + (b,) for a, b in zip(a, b)]
[('x', 4, 6), ('y', 1, 2), ('z', 5, 3)]
```

Your code created a product; for each separate element in `b` you added all of `a`; that means you added all of your expected output *3 times*, instead of just once.